# Unable to download from any browser

Tags: networking, browser, download

I have noticed that I am not able to download anything from my browser.

I can use the webpage to browse through the internet, but when I decide to download something the page just goes into error connection timed out.

I was able to download things before this error occurred today when I ran my computer.

What i have tried:

I tried changing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments` selecting *"ScanWithAntiVirus"* doubleclicking it and changing it to **1**.

Then I rebooted the computer and same result. 
I have googled for this and here is the link [Page that i have tried](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1879088/download-browser.html)

Update 1: So i still can't download, but i can download thing's from this  [page.](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/windows/) What could be causing this?

I am unable to download following things: 
[Uplay][3]
[Steam][4]
[Java][5]

BundleId=220284_d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried with more than one browsers?

Comment: I have tried Internet Explorer and Chrome. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by re-installing my computer :)